# Improve my running

Tags: running, running-training-plan

I'm 31 and I started to run since December 2016. Currently I've 8 months running without any training plan, my schedule is this:

1. Run 3 or 4 time per week, leaving one day to rest between running day.
2. Do intervals, mixing 500 mts running 80%, rest 15 seconds.
3. Running on hills (Only 1 km)

Ok, I think my training is not ok, because when I rest more than one day, when I back to run I feel tired. Also for me is imposible to run more than 4km without walk to rest.

My Question is, How can I organize my training?? Any play for?? Should I increase my running days???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't actually have facts to support my answer, but I will respond speaking from personal experience.

I am a 28 year old female and I started running when I was around 13 and also played soccer and tennis. I would say for me just doing any kind of cardio improves my run. I run every other day at least for 30 mins. On the other days, I play soccer. When you play another sport, it forces you to sprint short distances, rest/walk in between and sprint again, there by increasing your endurance, so when you actually go for a run, you end up running longer and faster without feeling like you need a break. Also, I alternate between long distance 10min mile for about 6miles(which ends up being about 12min mile) on day one of running.

Second running day, I do a short 2-3 mile run and push myself to average 7-8.30min mile. Day 3 of run day, I do sprints. I actually count up to 100 in my head while sprinting as hard as I can, then walk counting till 200. On the next sprint, I count till 150, walk for 300. I do so until I can't any more and then walk back home haha. Generally I found, sprinting is the key to improving running without feeling like you have to rest when you go on runs. Running up a hill will definitely increase your endurance so keep doing that. Don't be discouraged, every time you go for a run, run an extra minute from your last run ,i.e. if you ran 28 mins, total last time, run 30 mins total this time; or run an extra .2 miles this rime from your last run distance. It makes a whole lot of a difference. Don't give up and stay active. Don't give  up, keep records of what you did last time and try to beat your record the next time.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Thanks for your Advice I'm trying that and I feel some progress :D

Answer (score 5):

For cardio training, a big question in the past few years seemed to have been:

***Should people engage in HITT (high intensity training intervals) or Steady State Training?***

If you're new to HIIT, HIIT is cardio training that alternates between high-intensity and low-intensity exercise. Another answer here touches on that subject and a real life example of HIIT would be if you sprinted for 60 seconds, and walked for 120 seconds, and continued on cycling through that process of sprinting and walking.

Just going by your description above, you're likely not new to steady state cardio. Steady state is where you are constantly running/jogging/biking/etc at the same pace/effort throughout the entire activity; there is no variance in intensity.

Some fitness websites believe that HITT is the best type of cardio training to engage in if your desire is to burn fat. In this [article](https://www.builtlean.com/2010/06/04/high-intensity-interval-training-hiit-best-cardio-to-burn-fat/) on Built Lean the author argues that

- HIIT is the best cardio to burn fat
- HIIT results in increased aerobic capacity
- HIIT results in increased lactate threshold
- HIIT results in improved insulin sensitivity
- HIIT results in the anabolic effect

Of course, Built Lean is not the only fitness website that agrees on the advantages of HIIT over steady state. Mens Fitness and BodyBuilding.com feel the exact same way. Interestingly enough, BodyBuilding.com makes a case for including both types of cardio training into your workout routine in this article [here](https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/going-steady-5-reasons-to-do-steady-state-cardio.html).

In [The Effects of High Intensity Interval Training vs Steady State Training on Aerobic and Anaerobic Capacity](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4657417/), an article from the Journal of Sports Science and Medicine, a study has revealed some interesting results about HIIT versus steady state training:

> our results suggest no particular advantage for very high intensity training models, such as that which has been widely adapted from the results of Tabata et al. (1996)

First, I do want to say this study was on the Tabata regimen, and since then we've developed the Gibala, Zuniga, and Timmons regimen. But, in the choice of which cardio program you should choose, apparently the results of the study suggest that either works. What I found most significant in the study:

> The observation that the Tabata protocol was less enjoyable is not surprising. The progressive loss of enjoyment across all the protocols suggests that perhaps variety in the type of exercise is as important as the type of exercise per se. Particularly considering that the health benefits of exercise have to be viewed in the context of the likelihood that exercise is continued for several years

This all sort of resonates well with me because when I first got back into exercising, I found myself plagued by a lack of enjoyment. I found that if

- I was at the gym, I needed to vary the machines throughout my one hour cardio session. I could not be on the elliptical for an hour straight. I had to switch up the machines and I had to switch up the modes. Some machines were strictly cardio trying to maintain "x" heart rate. Some other cardio machines were for building resistance, and so on and so forth.
- If I was running in my neighborhood or at the park, I couldn't just run 3 miles at 8 minutes per mile. I needed to run 3 miles to get to the park, then participate in HIIT once I got there, then run back home at 8 minutes per mile.

Personally, what I found most successful (because believe me, I did initially struggle for a long time figuring out what made me happy) is

- engaging in cardio daily to maintain the habit
- making every cardio session different to prevent lack of enjoyment
- always trying to improve on previous records so that you have something to look forward to which is really just a form of motivation.

I say records because it will be different depending on your goals.

- If you run 1 mile today, run 1.1 miles tomorrow.
- If you run 1 mile in 9 minutes, shoot for 8:55 or 8:50 on the next run

Smalls steps are the best route for improvement in cardio.

My advice to you would be to decide whether or not you want to continue steady state, incorporate HIIT instead, or engage in a combination of both. You should also develop short and long term goals for whichever cardio training you prefer to use.